# accessing current item on .each()

Tags: jquery, this, each

i have the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="step-holder">
    <div class="step-no">1</div>
    <div class="step-dark-left"><a href="#">Basic details</a></div>
    <div class="step-dark-right">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="step-no-off">2</div>
    <div class="step-light-left"><a href="#">SEO</a></div>
    <div class="step-light-right">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="step-no-off">3</div>
    <div class="step-light-left"><a href="#">Preview</a></div>
    <div class="step-light-round">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#step-holder a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.step-light-left').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('.step-light-left').addClass('.step-dark-left');
    });
});
```

but the second `$(this)` (inside the `.each`) still reffers to the original `$(this)`.
so, it does not work.

how can this be acheieved ? i dont understand why the second `$(this)` does not refer to the `.each()` current item.

or maybe, if you have another solution to change all `step-light-left` to `step-light-right` and the other way around.

what i need to do is turn off all the 'non-clicked' divs and turn on the clicked one.

Comment: Got a HTML snippet to go along with the javascript? It should work, there might be another problem

Comment: Your code looks okay, `this` should be different. Could you put a working sample on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: lol , if i could put a WORKING sample.. i would not ask this ;)

Comment: @Dementic I meant working "broken" example :)

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `.each`, you can just tack `.removeClass(...).addClass(...)` on to it. Chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

```
$('#step-holder a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#step-holder > div').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'step-dark-left') {
            $(this).removeClass('step-dark-left');
            $(this).addClass('step-light-left');
        }
    });
    $(this).parent().removeClass('step-light-left');
    $(this).parent().addClass('step-dark-left');
});
```

Comment: how come ?
the solution is very related to what i asked, i also asked for your own solutions if there are any ideas of a way doing it diffrently. please re-read the question.

Comment: i didn't mean to sound aggressive.. It's just that the question, originally, was about changing the parent of the clicked element.. not about the rest of the `.dark` elements.. and @pixelfreak's answer solved that issue..

Comment: The question was never about changing the parent of the clicked element, maybe i didnt explain myself good enough.

Comment: The code implied that. Now, the updated question is clear about what you want :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem might not be due to the scope of `this`.

This line is wrong:

`$(this).removeClass('.step-light-left').addClass('.step-dark-left');`

It should be:

`$(this).removeClass('step-light-left').addClass('step-dark-left');`

No dots. Try that.

Adding Chris comment: You don't really need to use .each(), you can just add/remove the class directly on the selector.

**More addition**: If you want to turn off all "non-clicked" divs and turn on clicked one, what if you define a single class called "active" or something. Then, you just do something like this inside your click function:

```
$('#step-holder .active').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: @Dementic Can you define "as it should"? :) See my answer again, added something

Comment: about the 'active' class, even due i am open to suggestions, usually, a project have been worked for quite a time, and making changes is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

Parent of "#step-holder a" is the div containing the "a" tag, not the #step-holder div. I've added another parent function call:

```
$('#step-holder a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.step-light-left').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('step-light-left').addClass('step-dark-left');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are asking in the updated question with a single chain of methods..

```
$('#step-holder a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent()
        .removeClass('step-light-left')
        .addClass('step-dark-left')
        .siblings('.step-dark-left')
        .removeClass('step-dark-left')
        .addClass('step-light-left');
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zSXnm/3/